# Why Qt Maintenance Tool doesn't show any components that I haven't installed?

Tags: qt, qt5

['Select Components' page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmncF.png)
My Qt version is 5.14.0, why all the components showed in this list on the 'Select Components' page are all I had installed? How can I install those that I haven't installed? For example components for Android? Any help would be appreciated:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to check/uncheck the category filters in the right column to show more components.

It could also mean that you have already installed all the compatible modules for your environment.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, mmerle. I'd tried every filter on the right—Archive, LTS, Latest releases, Preview, but none will show the components that I haven't installed:(

Comment: Today I checked all the checkboxes in the right column(Archive, Latest supported releases, Preview), and then clicked the Filter button, the problem is solved, I can see all the components that I haven't installed now. I did the same thing, but why I didn't solve the problem two years ago? I guess the reason is that I've updated Qt Maintenance Tool this time. Thank you for your reply, mmerle and Emil.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem a few times. Usually what helps me is first removing the c:\Users<user>\AppData\Local\cache\qt-unified-windows-online directory, re-running Maintenance Tool and checking the Archive checkbox.